# Boost site in search results with XRANK / KQL

Tags: sharepoint-search, kql

I have a group of sites included in an enterprise search center. One particular site I'd like to have more weight in search results relevancy than the others. How do I use XRANK to do that? I've made a few tries at the syntax and can't seem to get it to work. Example is below. I'd like siteA to have a large boost.

`{searchboxquery} (Path:http://siteA) XRANK(NB=1.5) Path:siteb Path:sitec Path:sited`

Answer (score 0):

Do this by creating a query rule. This query rule can be added on the server or on the site iteself.

In the search Site
By editing the search results webpart and clicking on "change Query" in the web part toolbox
Click on the sort tab
Select Sort By ->rank
In this tab you can add a dynamic ordering rule and change the ranking when "URL Starts with" 
Add your value and select your modifier Promote or demote

In Central admin, this is a bit more complicated
It is possible to either adjust your context on "searchable" managed metadata or create a query rule that promotes the values based on a match

In addition, creating a ranking model

I suggest you take a look at these sites...
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871676.aspx
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/03/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169065.aspx

I'm sorry but this is not such an easy answer as it truly depends on your search schema\architecture

Answer (score 0):

In your search, you can add dynamic ordering rules to promote/demote certain results. [image]

And if you click test, you should see this in your query:

```
     XRANK(cb=5000.00) "Path:http://siteA"
```